# Good run time in mysql 5.0 without index but not in 5.1

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a database created by MySQL 5.0.

Tables have not index except primary key field.

I have a query and run time is 0.9 s in MySQL 5.0. when i export database and import to newer MySql version like 5.1 (i have tested 5.5 too) with same hardware run time query is 120 s.

if i index fileds on join i get  a 0.2 run time.

my question is then why i have a good run time in MySQL 5.0 without index?

what is difference between 5.0 and 5.1 (5.5)?

Comment: Are you sure it was not indexed? or was the query results cached?

Comment: yes. i am sure from caching. and indexs wasn't in structure details. and if mysql 5.0 had index then why it didnt work in 5.1 !?

Answer (score 1):

The question is *really*

"Do I need an index, or don't I?"

The only way to answer this question is to know your application, and profile your database queries.

In general, if performance is OK, if a table is reasonably small, and if your queries (and, more importantly, your *joins*) aren't particularly "selective", then typically you DON'T necessarily want to create an index.

Here's a good summary of "selectivity" (and some good advice on indexing in general):

> http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1423-Rick-Osborne-On-Database-Indexing-And-SQL-Best-Practices.htm
>
> Selectivity in a nutshell: Your data is a card catalog in a library.
>   (Remember those things?) Or a filing cabinet full of manila folders.
>   An index is the tabs on the cards or folders that helps you find what
>   you are looking for. Selectivity is the ratio of unique keys to the
>   total number of rows.

Remember, too, that there are LOTS of variables that determine "performance".  "DB Version" and "indexing" are just two of many.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to comment on paulsm4, but I don't have enough privileges (yet).
Your answer is not so smart, for this reason :

The question is not : "Do I need an index, or don't I?"

but?

Why when I got an no index, no cache , and the same data, 5.1 (and 5.5) is a hundreds of time slower than 5.0 ?
-> No idea...

and

What are the differences between 5.0 and 5.1 ?
-> Check the mysql official changelog

---

Next time I see a homeless in the street, asking me one $, I'll answer him ***really*** : The question is not "can I have one $ (please)?" but
"How can I become multimillionaire quickly?"

and then...I'll continue my way spending my $ on a random cheap soda can.

---